# Prove the following subset of $X = \mathbb{T}^2$ is not a submanifold of $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential, submanifold

I am having trouble understanding the proof of the following statement:

> Let $X = T^2$ be the 2-dimensional torus defined as  $$T^2 :=
> \mathbb{R}^2 / \sim $$ where $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ iff $x-x', y-y' \in
>  \mathbb{Z}$. Prove the following subset is not a submanifold: $$ Y =
>  \{[(t^2,t^3)] \in X \hspace{3pt} |\hspace{3pt} t \in \mathbb{R}\} $$

The proof is as follows: Assume it is a submanifold, then theres an open neighbourhood $U$ of $[(0,0)]$ and a homeomorphism $f : U \cap Y \to V$ where $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ open. If $\epsilon > 0 $ is sufficiently small then $U \cap Y$ contains the set $W_0$ of points $[(t^2,t^3)]$ where $-\epsilon < t < \epsilon$.

By definition of $X$ there exists $\epsilon ' >0$ sufficiently small such that $U \cap Y$ contains the set $W_1$ of points $[(s^2-1, s^3-1)]$ where $1-\epsilon' < s < 1+\epsilon'$.

From here notice $W_0$ and $W_1$ are distinct connected subsets of $U \cap Y$ containing $[(0,0)] $ which gives the contradiction since there are no open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ containing connected subsets meeting at just one point.

My questions:

1. I don't understand why $U \cap Y$ contains $W_1$. I think its to do with the equivalence relation but I don't immediately see why this is true.
2. I don't understand why $W_0$ and $W_1$ are distinct connected subsets of $U \cap Y$ containing $(0,0)$.
3. What is the intuitive idea behind why this cannot be a submanifold?

Working with $T^2$ I always find confusing because of the equivalence relation. I get really confused trying to visualise it all!

I would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Try to draw out the curve on a piece of paper and try to see what happens near $0$ due to identifications

Comment: The proof is seriously confusing as stated. It is easier to show that $Y$ contains a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so it cannot be homeomorphic to any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Masacroso How is the curve closed?

Comment: @duelspace because $[(0,0)]=[(1,1)]$, so the map $\gamma :[0,1]\to Y,\,t\mapsto [(t^2,t^3)]$ defines a closed curve in $Y$

Comment: Ah I see thank you @Masacroso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential idea here is that if it were a submanifold then it should just look like an interval in a neighbourhood around $0$. However it looks like the picture below near $0$.[image: Y near 0]

If $Y$ were submanifold it should have just been an interval, however here it looks like two crossed lines.

Comment: Following your previous comment, i did try to draw it out. I know what $\{(t^2,t^3)\}$ will look like but I get really confused trying to think about $\{[(t^2,t^3)]\}$. How do the identifications come into play? I don't see why you would get 2 lines as you do in your diagram.

Comment: @duelspace The two curves I drew are (t^2,t^3) for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $(t^2-1,t^3-1)$ and $1 \leq t \leq 2$. The identifications show that $[t^2,t^3]$ is same as the equivalence class of $[t^2-1,t^3-1]$. So the interval around $t=0$ and $t=1$ would actually end up around $0$ in the identification.

Comment: @duelspace I am lying a bit about the range of the parameter $t$, but  I hope it does not lead to any confusion

Comment: @happymath I see! So, if i'm not mistaken if we were to consider even more intervals of $t$ we would end up with a bunch of line segments which start on the y-axis and branch out, right? Is that correct?

With regards to the original question, the idea is this: If we pick a neighbourhood U around the origin, $f(U \cap Y)$ is the union of two distinct line segments meeting at a single point. This cannot be homeomorphic to any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ thus we have a contradiction. Would you agree with this?

Comment: @duelspace that sounds about right

Comment: Thank you for your help!